# Move away from cloud66 and deploy to azure via commandline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, cloud66

So i have a nice rails app working fine via cloud66

However I don't need the expense of cloud66 anymore. I was using cloud66 to deploy and run migrations and rake tasks (can use whenever gem for this)

I'm wondering how I can remove the middleman of cloud66 and just deploy manually to the existing cloud66 created App?

I've looked at this here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-deploy-local-git

But i'm not 100% sure if this is what i need?

Any help or hints/tips would be great!!

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your app manually by using tools like Capistrano and you can manage *(upgrading packages, rolling updates, scaling, configuring firewalls, database management etc)* your own backups and scale via your cloud provider. But the aim of Cloud 66 is to maintain the whole lifecycle of your app easy, so you can focus on development rather than ops tasks. (disclaimer: I work at Cloud 66)